# How to change cursor theme in a specific application

Tags: gnome, mouse-pointer

I am using ungoogled-chromium. I want to change how the cursor changes when it points to hyperlinks. It is different from how the cursor behaves in other apps. How do I change it for this application?

Comment: By any chance, did you install it as a snap/flatpak? Then, installing it as a deb package will solve the issue.

Comment: Understood. I will try and report back.